# R: Change value in one column based upon value in another column in a dataframe

Tags: r

I have an exceedingly simple question I couldn't find a way to do simply.

I have a dataframe, a column of which contains school type.  Categories include rural, inner-city, suburban, private, etc.  I want to create a new category that collapses these categories down into just rural vs. non-rural. What is the easiest way to do this?

I ended up doing this:

```
data$rural <- "non-rural"
data[which(data$schtypek == "rural school"), ]$rural <- "rural"
```

I'm hoping there's an easier way.

Thanks!

Comment: The which() is not needed and would seem more natural to use: `data$rural[ data$schtypek == "rural school"] <- "rural"`

Comment: you can make a key like so `c(a = 'z', b = 'g', c = 'f')[letters[c(1,1,3,2,1,3,1,2)]]`

Comment: Could do it in one fell swoop with `data$rural <- ifelse(data$schtypek == "rural school", "rural", "non-rural")`